# PHP - Making News Site - increase Num Value - using Wrong Syntax in Foreach Loop -

Tags: php, html, foreach

**Question:** I'm making a Sidebar. And ive included PHP to write the different sections of the page. I want to add an id for my checkboxes and trying to add a number that increases with every foreach loop.

Its three rowes I'm interested in:

```
$num2 = 1; // Want to set a num value. <br>
printf('<input id="check' + $num2 + '" type="checkbox">'); //Add the Num value to ID.. 
$num2++; //Increase num value per Loop
```

But Must be Using Wrong Syntax or something for using this method My Site looks more like a hurricane gone by.  https://snag.gy/KNwB4x.jpg

This is how my Website looks when I remove the `' + $num2 + '` on row two:

https://snag.gy/mjn4Yh.jpg

Full Code:

```
<?php
  $num2 = 1;
    $sidebaritems = array("Business", "Technology", "Politics", "World",
        "Sports", "Opinion", "Health");

foreach ($sidebaritems as $sitem) {
  printf('<li><a href="#">');
  printf('<div class="row">');
  printf('<div class="col-sm-1">');
  printf('<i class="fa fa-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  printf('</div>');
  printf('<div class="col-sm-5">');
  printf('<p class="sidebar-text"> %s</p>', $sitem);
  printf('</div>');
  printf('<div class="col-sm-2">');
  printf('<i class="fa faa-burst animated-hover fa-dot-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  printf('</div>');
  printf('<div class="col-sm-2">');
  printf('<label class="switch"><input id="check' + $num2 + '" type="checkbox"  checked>');
  printf('<div class="slider round"></div></label>');
  printf('</div>');
  printf('</div>');
  printf('</a></li>');
  $num2++;
  } ?>
```

Comment: So open generated html and see what is wrong

Comment: Concatenation in php is done with `.` by the way.

Comment: Why there is a name tag on div `<div class="col-sm-5" name="contact` ??

Comment: I think i tried to do that but got alittle confused.. Im pretty sure 105% that it is the + $num2 + that is wrongly written by me. So If someone could help me I be very happy! :)

Comment: `printf('<label class="switch"><input id="check' . $num2 . '" type="checkbox"  checked>');`

Comment: @PraveenKumar: dont worry. I experimented just with the code while i was fixing it.. it shouldnt be a name there.

Comment: ah is it . not + ? :)

Comment: @DJoe `+` is used in javascript or jquery `.` for php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
printf('<div class="col-sm-5" name="contact' . $num2 .  '">');
```

'+' operator in php adds two values numerically. Use '.' instead.

Comment: I add you informer. And Praveen and U_mulder who apperently answered me firrst. I didn't see that. if I could. Thanks to you both. 

Just waiting 5min because I can't add answer to quickly =)